# Dynamic resource based authorization for api endpoints

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a dotnet api and I'm having trouble with making permissions properly dynamic.  The permissions are based on user roles and claims.

A user may have one of four roles:

1. Admin User - can access everything
2. District User - can access all buildings and students in one or more district
3. Building User - can access all students in one more buildings
4. Student User - can access only students that they have claims for.

So a district user automatically gets all building claims for a district and a building user gets claims for one or more buildings and so forth.

I want to create policies based on the resource they are trying to access.  So I have something like the following:

```cs
    // GET: api/v1/Student/5
    [Authorize(Policy="StudentPolicy")]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<StudentDto>> GetStudent(int id)
    {
        var _student = await _studentService.GetByIdAsync(id);

        return Ok(_student);
    }
```

```cs
    // in my startup configuration
    options.AddPolicy(
       "StudentPolicy",
       policy =>   policy.Requirements.Add(new SingleStudentPolicyRequirement(// pass param? )));
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, StudentPolicyHandler>(// param?);
```

```cs
    // the policy requirement
    public class SingleStudentPolicyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
      private readonly int _student;
      public SingleStudentPolicyRequirement(int student) {
           _student=student
      }
    }
```

```cs
    // the policy handler
    public class StudentPolicyHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SingleStudentPolicyRequirement>
  { 
      public StudentPolicyHandler() { }

      protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        SingleStudentPolicyRequirement requirement
      )
      {
        // profit?
        return Task.CompletedTask;
      }
  }
```

I'm just having trouble figuring out the right approach to inject policy with the parameter being the resource they're requesting.  In the above case, the student via his id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I think you want to inject policy with the parameter, But the value of parameter changes with the value of parameter in `GetStudent()` method, So it's hard to inject this parameter. In my opinion, When user access `GetStudent()`  method, you can use httpcontext to get the id.

```
public class SingleStudentPolicyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {

    }


public class StudentPolicyHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SingleStudentPolicyRequirement>
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;

        public StudentPolicyHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SingleStudentPolicyRequirement requirement)
        {
            var id = int.Parse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("id").ToString());
            if (xxxxxx)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else {
                context.Fail();
            }
            

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

**Program.cs**

```
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
                
            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(x => x.AddPolicy(

               "StudentPolicy",
               policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new SingleStudentPolicyRequirement())
            ));

            builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, StudentPolicyHandler>();
```

Hope this answer can give you some help.

Comment: I had that thought.  With the `IHttpContextAccessor` become globally available after `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`?

Comment: Yes, From this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0), It is a recommended approach to access httpcontext in custom components.

Comment: Thank you! In retrospect, obvious... but